# ios 7 custom transition not working for navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, transition

I'm testing around the new iOS 7 custom transition API but i have some troubles with the navigation controller case. I tried a very basic test for the moment with this :

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
}
```

As you guessed, this code do nothing except to complete the transition with no animations.
But here's the problem : if it's working normally with present / dismiss a controller, all i see with push and pop methods is a black screen, as if `[transitionContext completeTransition:YES]` didn't work.

I've set all the delegate properties and delegate methods properly, since this method is called all the time (present, dismiss, push, pop).

Did someone already face this issue ?

Comment: do you mean `[transitionContext completeTransition:YES]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something more like this, I was having trouble with it as well and this helped make more sense of it

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{

    // 1. obtain state from the context
    UIViewController *toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    CGRect finalFrame = [transitionContext finalFrameForViewController:toViewController];

    // 2. obtain the container view
    UIView *containerView = [transitionContext containerView];

    // 3. set initial state
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]; toViewController.view.frame =
    CGRectOffset(finalFrame, 0, screenBounds.size.height); 

    // 4. add the view
    [containerView addSubview:toViewController.view];

    // 5. animate
    NSTimeInterval duration = [self transitionDuration:transitionContext];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{

        toViewController.view.frame = finalFrame; 

     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        // 6. inform the context of completion
        [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];

    }];
}
```

Source: http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=8851

Comment: This line `[containerView addSubview:toViewController.view];` make my code work. It seems that we always need to add destination view to container view, even if we use a snapshot view for animaton. Thx for pointing me on the right direction.